# Problema em deixar um video fixo no background de uma section

Tags: html, css

[image: ex:]

( o background da section fica fixo, mas o video não )

Alguém poderia me ajudar a  deixar o video fixo igual a bg da section?

codigo:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Paytone+One');
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: helvetica;
}



header{
 z-index: 5;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 70px;
 background-color: #fff;
 -webkit-transition: background-color .5s;
}

nav{
 display: table;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 15px;
 height: 40px;
 -webkit-transition: margin-left .5s;
}

ul{
 margin-right: 850px;
 display: block;
 float: right;
 list-style: none;
}

ul li{
 float: left;
 margin: 10px;

}

ul a{
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-transition: color .1s;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    background-color: #3F51B5;
    color: #fff;
}
.center{
    text-align: center;
}

.parallax-target{
    min-height: 650px;
    background: transparent center fixed;

}

.parallax-targett{
    min-height: 600px;
    background: transparent;
}
.parallax-targettt{
    min-height: 600px;

}

.middle{
    min-height: 400px;
}
.slide{
 background-image: url(../img/2853636-firewatch-wallpapers.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: cover;
 width: 100%;
 height: 700px;
}
.content{

}
```

```html
  <section class="slide">
   <div class="content">
<p style="text-align: center;"> <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/QN_FdiMItvA?autoplay=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;nologo=1&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;theme=light&amp;wmode=opaque&amp;controls=0" width="690" height="400" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></p>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retire a tag `<p>` que não serve para centralizar elementos desse tipo.

Você pode tornar o vídeo responsivo com a largura máxima definida no atributo `width` do `iframe`. Pegar a proporção da *largura* e *altura* e inserir um jQuery que irá centralizar e tornar seu vídeo responsivo e centralizado na página:

Adicione o CSS referente ao `iframe` que irá fixá-lo e centralizá-lo:

```
iframe{
   position: fixed;
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
}
```

**HTML do iframe:**

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/sVxBaRYnjgE?autoplay=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;nologo=1&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;theme=light&amp;wmode=opaque&amp;controls=0" width="690" height="400" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(window).on("load resize", function(e){
   var vid = $("iframe");

   if(e.type == "load"){
      var vid_w_tag = vid.attr("width");
      var vid_h_tag = vid.attr("height");
      proporcao = vid_w_tag/vid_h_tag;
      vid.attr("width","100%")
      .css('max-width', vid_w_tag+'px');
   }

   var vid_w = vid.width();
   vid.attr('height',vid_w/proporcao);
});
```

Comment: Opa mano só estou com um problema agora ele está acompanhando o scroll até o final da page, mas tipo eu queria q o video ficasse fixo nesse background: https://imgur.com/a/AynPM, mas ele ta ficando assim : https://imgur.com/a/Y7bPq

Comment: @Felipe Tenta trocando o position: fixed por position: absolute

Comment: O absolute  deu certo, mas pode me tirar só mais uma duvida? qnd eu adiciono o background-attachment: fixed; no background o video não fica fixo não tem jeito de arrumar isso? Ou a script eu importei errado?

Comment: @Felipe cara, o background não tem nada a ver com o video. Uma coisa diferente da outra

Comment: Tipo assim mano eu coloquei o iframe dentro de um section e essa section eu chamei um background img, bg no repeat, bg size, bg attachment fixed e tipo por causa do attachment fixed o video não fixa fica fixo e eu tava querendo fazer

Comment: um efeito junto ao parallax

Comment: o q eu estou tentando fazer é igual ao video e o bg do video dessa page aqui: https://elojobbrasil.com.br/.

Comment: @Felipe Não tem como entender isso. O background da section é uma coisa, oq tem dentro da section é oura coisa. Background nada mais é que uma imagem no fundo, não atrapalha em nada nos elementos.

Comment: @Felipe Mas isso aí eh coisa mais complexa. Envolve muitas coisas.

Comment: Pois é eu também não estou entendendo pq fica assim o video movimenta qnd eu desco o scroll quando eu utilizo o attachment na section,  eu vou te mandar um jsfiddle só com o css e html dessa parte pra vc ver se errei em algo.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/akpuavkr/ @dvd eu sei, mas estava tentando fazer só essa parte do video deles lá, se tiver como vc dar uma olhada e ver se tem algo errado no codigo.

Comment: @Felipe No JSFiddel não aparece nada, só os códigos. Coisas assim são complicadas, tem que fazer parte por parte, ir testando

Comment: ah não sabia q era tão complexo então vou deixar eles dois fixos mesmo :( .

Comment: Mas obrgd por tirar minha duvida bro!

Comment: @Felipe Fazer efeito paralax eh dificil, tem que saber muito de CSS e JavaScript

Comment: Eu consegui fzr algo bem legal com o plugin e ta atendendo bem até, a única coisa q pegou foi nessa parte ai q eu queria deixar um video fixo + bg .